# Databases won't merge even though they have same columns. problem when importing?

Tags: r, excel, dplyr, merge, tidyverse

I am having problems merging data frames and I think the error is in the importing of the database from excel. I think this is the case as I tried to do it manually with a dummy example and it worked. When I made an excel with the dummy example and imported it did not work. I cannot do the same for my data, as it is huge, but I cannot seem to find an error. I would really appreciate your help.

Here is what I was trying to do. First, I will show you a dummy example that worked.

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14')) 
jobname <- c('a','b','c')

data1= data.frame(employee, salary, stardate)
data2=data.frame(employee, salary, jobname)

newdata=merge(data1, data2)

newdata
```

We merged the two data frames based on common columns and the result was the new data frame with 3 observations and 4 columns.

When I import two datasets (data1 and data2) and try to merge them, I do not get this result, instead, I get a table with 9 observations and 4 columns. When I imported the same values of a factor are not recognised as such. for this reason, I think it must be an excel to r problem, but have no idea where to look for?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Can you share the imported datasets `data1` and `data2` ?

Comment: Consider converting your factor columns to character columns, or else explicitly setting the possible values of your factors using the `levels` argument of `factor()` . R treats factors more like integers behind the scenes ([read more here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html)), and if not all possible values are included in both data frames, or if they're introduced in a different order, this is probably messing up your joins.

Comment: @ChristopherBelanger Thanks for your response. I did that also and it did not work. I also tried splitting the full database (not the example one but my working one) into two smaller databases with one common column and then re-joining them, and it also creates this error. Why would this happen when it is working from the same database? Thanks a lot again

Comment: @RonakShah how can I share the datasets via the comment?

Comment: You may use `dput` to share the datasets `dput(data1)` and `dput(data2)`.

Comment: dput(data1)
structure(list(employee = c("John Doe", "Peter Gynn", "Jolie Hope"
), salary = c(21000, 23400, 26800), startdate = structure(c(1288569600, 
1206403200, 1173830400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
> dput(data2)
structure(list(employee = c("John Doe", "Peter Gynn", "Jolie Hope"
), salary = c(21000, 23400, 26800), jobname = c("a", "b", "c"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data you provided, you can join the two datasets using the function `left_join()`.  Here's a working example:

```
library(dplyr)

# set up our two sample data sets
data1 <- structure(list(employee = c("John Doe", "Peter Gynn", "Jolie Hope" ), 
                        salary = c(21000, 23400, 26800), 
                        startdate = structure(c(1288569600, 1206403200, 1173830400), 
                                              class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), 
                   row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) 



data2 <- structure(list(employee = c("John Doe", "Peter Gynn", "Jolie Hope" ), 
                        salary = c(21000, 23400, 26800), 
                        jobname = c("a", "b", "c" )), 
                   row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
                   class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" )) 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             jobname = c("a", "b", "c" )), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ))

# left-join the datasets, matching the "employee" and "salary" columns
left_join(data1, 
          data2,
          by = c("employee", "salary"))
```

Let me know if you were trying to do something different.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. With this example it works indeed, so I will provide a slice of my data and an example where the left_join is not working. I will do it in the comment below due to space.

Comment: dput(age)
structure(list(Sample.new = c("1-Sc-N-2011", "1-Sc-N-2011", "1-Sc-N-2011", 
"1-Sc-N-2011", "1-Sc-N-2011", "1-Sc-N-2011", "1-Sc-N-2011", "1-Sc-N-2011", 
"1-Sc-N-2011", "1-Sc-N-2011"), age.years = c(4.761122519, 4.761122519, 
4.761122519, 4.761122519, 4.761122519, 4.761122519, 4.761122519, 
4.761122519, 4.761122519, 4.761122519)), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: dput(species)
structure(list(Sample.new = c("1-Sc-N-2011", "1-Sc-N-2011", "1-Sc-N-2011", 
"1-Sc-N-2011", "1-Sc-N-2011", "1-Sc-N-2011", "1-Sc-N-2011", "1-Sc-N-2011", 
"1-Sc-N-2011", "1-Sc-N-2011"), Final.Taxa = c("Clytia hemisphaerica", 
"Spirobranchus triqueter", "Verruca stroemia", "Mytilus edulis", 
"Phtisica marina", "Pisidia longicornis", "Alcyonium digitatum", 
"Actiniaria", "Asterias rubens", "Stenothoe monoculoides")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: The two comments above are the two dataframes that I want to join. When I do        > newdata=left_join(age, species, by='Sample.new') the new dataframe does not recognise the 'Samples.new'. As the same and increases the number of rows. The newdata frame should be 20 rows and have 3 variables, but it has 380 rows and 3 variables. I hope I am not too confusing, do you get the same error as well? @Christopher Belanger

Comment: Ah, it's because every row has the same value for `Sample.new`, namely `1-Sc-N-2011`. A left-join works best when each observation has a unique identifier. Here they have the same identifier, so it's returning all possible matches. So one option would be to assign each row a unique ID in both data frames so that they join properly. But if the observations are already in order and you just want to attach them to each other, you could use `dplyr::bind_cols(age, species)` (although note it will rename the duplicate columns) or even just `species$age.years <- age$age.years`.